# Qt jambi Eclipse integration problem

Tags: java, eclipse, qt, user-interface, qt-jambi

I've just install the libqtjambi 4.7.2 by PPA in Ubuntu Natty 11.04. When I turned into integration with Eclipse it asked me to give the jambi installation path. But with apt-get I have only `/usr/share/java` but it doesn't work.

Any help?

EDIT:

darkjh@jh:~$ sudo apt-cache show libqtjambi | grep Version:
Version: 4.7.2~c4f2573~3017~2920~natty1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide the output of:

```
apt-cache show libqtjambi | grep Version:
```

This is a known problem, since open-jdk is including the required patches by default while sun-jdk isn't.

If you are using open-jdk the only thing you have to do is to include the qtjambi-4.7.2.jar in your buildpath from */usr/share/java*.

However if you are using sun-jdk you also have to change the native jar location to */usr/lib:/usr/lib/jni*.

If you aren't familiar with Eclipse, both operations (including the qtjambi-4.7.2.jar and changing the Native Library location) are shown on the following screencast: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RauQba4Qgh4

Comment: I did like in the video, both .jar file and the native library location. But Eclipse still gives me error with line "package com.trolltech.examples;" and others.

Comment: Could you provide the full error (pastebin) log and an example program what you want to compile?

ps.:you are using the latest version, it runs fine here.